# How to scan multiple images to single PDF Linux command line - scanimage

Tags: python, shell, debian, sane

I am trying to scan multiple documents via ADF to a single file using scanimage.

```
scanimage --batch
```

but batch creates multiple files. Is it possible to save all documents as a single file?

scanimage is preferred but python-sane solutions are welcome as  well.

Thanks in advance.